# When would I want Rapid Firecannon over Statikk Shiv or Phantom Dancer?

Tags: league-of-legends

Regarding the new AD Carry itemization implemented for Season 6, we have some new options. I try to main the ADC role, but I feel like itemization just got a little more confusing. (it felt fairly simple before, most ADC's all bought the same items).

So the question is, when (or on which champions) is it a good idea to pick Rapid Firecannon over Statikk Shyv or Phantom Dancer?

They all grant some sort of bonus to attack speed, movement, and critical strike. Riot says RF is better for "sieging", but I mean, we all siege.

Comment: As a small note, surprisingly building both Statik Shiv and Rapid Firecannon has the highest win rate on Vayne as of November 17, 2015, according to Champion.gg. It's also a build that Gosu commonly uses (a popular Twitch streamer that plays Vayne at the Challenger/Master level).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They all give similar stats but it's their *unique perks* that set them apart.

Statikk Shiv gives better wave clear and area damage in teamfights, with the lightning damage proc. Pick this one if you have a teamfighting comp or need more waveclearing power on champs such as vayne or quinn.

Phantom Dancer gives better dueling potential through the reduced damage taken from your current target. Pick this is you like to split push and often end up in 1v1 situations.

Rapid Firecannon gives longer auto attack range and bonus damage on your next attack. You can hit towers from outside their attack range with it which is why Riot says this is best for sieging. Pick this if you have a heavy objective sieging or poke comp.

Comment: Riot mentions in the patch notes: *"It's worth noting that Energize isn't a unique passive, so both Statikk Shiv and Rapid Firecannon play together rather well!"* Are the specific play styles/champions where stacking them is recommended?

Comment: @clcto If you wanted to double down on the siege/poke comp I guess you could buy both. Though you may be better off with another damage item rather than more attack speed/crit. As usual it would depend on the game which is Riot's goal with season 6 anyways. I do wonder if rapid fire cannon affects Gangplank's Parrrley range at all. If so that would definitely be a good time to consider buying both.

Comment: It should also be noted that PD is still great on Vayne. She's a single target damage dealer and an assassin.

Comment: I can see Phantom Dancer being really useful too when you always get dived by a fed assassin, the % reduction damage can make the difference.

Comment: Try a both of them on a Draven. With his Q and an Infinity edge as well you can easily take 80-90% of a squishies hp in a single blow at quite some range.